# AWS get content using aws CLI

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-cli

I have an s3 object which stores a JSON file. 
Is there a way that I can fetch that object and store its content in a variable to perform JSON operations like getting value for key etc. using AWS cli.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course, you can do something like this in shell:

```
$ x=`aws s3 cp s3://bucketName/key -`
$ echo $x
{ "checked": false, "dimensions": { "width": 5, "height": 10 }, "id": 1, "name": "A green door", "price": 12.5, "tags": [ "home", "green" ] }
```

This key part of this cli command is the `-` at the end. It tells the command to write the output to stdout instead of a file.